# UnicodeEncodeError when receiving emoji unicode in JSON

Tags: python, json, spotify, spotipy

I'm receiving an JSON object of Spotify Playlist data using the Spotipy library. This playlsit data contains emojis in the 'name' field. This is throwing an exception when I try to print. For some reason I can't even access other sections of the JSON.

```
playlist_data = sp.search(q = 'best of ' + str(year),type = 'playlist',limit = 3)['playlists']
print(playlist_data)
```

gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spotify.py", line 111, in <module>
    get_ablum_by_year(i)
  File "spotify.py", line 89, in get_ablum_by_year
    print(playlist_data)
  File "C:\Users\jjent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u30c4' in position 349: character maps to <undefined>
```

Keeping the emoji is irrelevant to this solution, I just want to access the rest of the JSON but on these instances I get key errors when trying to parse the JSON.

Comment: Show us enough code to reproduce the problem and the full error traceback.

Comment: 'sp' is a Spotify API library, you would need an Client ID/Secret to reproduce the problem. Added the full traceback but I don't think it sheds much light

Comment: A traceback always contains useful information... Here `'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u30c4'` gives an offending character and allows to test a solution, and `...encodings\cp1252.py"` says that the charset used by print is cp1252.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is only at the `print` statement, and is caused by your Windows system using  a cp1252 encoding. That means that the previous Spotify call did correctly its job, and retrieved unicode characters absent from the 1252 code page.

A quick fix is to control the conversion before printing by encoding with `errors='replace'` and decoding back:

```
print(str(playlist_data).encode('cp1252', errors='replace').decode('cp1252'))
```

Any non cp1252 character will appear as a `?`.

This could be used for any other encoding by replacing `'cp1252'` by the appropriate encoding name.

Comment: This works! I need to convert it back to JSON and thats giving me some issues but I think I can sort them out, thanks!

Comment: @user3078867: the trick should only be used at print time. It is no use changing the value.

Comment: my problem re occur when using logging